# Codeigniter: How to avoid displaying duplicated values or overwrite a duplicated value in PHP foreach loop in a table?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm currently working on codeigniter. I want to display a value that is not been duplicated or overwrite a duplicated value from MySQL database into the datatable of PHP foreach loop.

Here is the picture my 2 tables in database:

[Table "employees" & table "times"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0yf0g.png)

Here is the relationship of my 2 tables:

[Relation of table "employees" & table "times"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c215b.png)

Here is my controller (home.php):

```
public function goPresent() { // attendance present page
    $this->load->model('Model_attendance');
    $query = $this->Model_attendance->getEmployees();
    $data['EMPLOYEES'] = null;
    if ($query) {
        $data['EMPLOYEES'] = $query;
    }
    $this->load->view('imports/header');
    $this->load->view('imports/menu');
    $this->load->view('attend', $data);
}
```

Here is my model (model_attendance.php):

```
class Model_attendance extends CI_Model {

    public $userID;
    public $username;
    public $password;
    public $totime;
    public $absence_type;
    public $date;
    public $hours;

    public function getEmployees() {
        $this->db->select("*");
        $this->db->from('times');
        $this->db->join('employees', 'employees.empnum = times.userID');
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result();
    }
}
```

Here is my view (attend.php):

```
<table class="table table-striped responsive-utilities jambo_table" id="myTable">
    <thead>
        <tr class="headings">
            <th>Employee No.</th>
            <th>Username</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Status</th> 
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php 
        foreach($EMPLOYEES as $employee){?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $employee->empnum; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $employee->username; ?></td> 
            <td><?php echo $employee->name; ?> <?php echo $employee->lastname; ?></td>
            <td><?php 
                if ($employee->hasClockOut==1){
                    echo '<a class="label label-danger">Inactive</a>';
                }else {
                    echo '<a class="label label-success">Active</a>';
                }
                ?></td> 
            </tr>
            <?php } ?>
        </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you Kevin for editing.

Comment: Do you mean if there's duplicate userID, it displays 1 only? sorry my english is bad

Comment: try: `$this->db->join('employees', 'employees.empnum = times.userID','left');`    you can also edit your table as unique values for column you want not dublicated

Comment: If there's a duplicated userID, I want it to avoid then it will display it into PHP foreach loop table.

Comment: It didn't work. Please provide me a full mvc code. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

on which basis you want unique values, just add this line in your query....

```
$this->db->group_by("column name which needs to be unique");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?php
                                $customers =   $this->db->group_by('customer_id')->get_where('registered_table' , array(
                                    'chat_group_id' => $group_id , 'year' => $reg_year
                                ))->result_array();
                                foreach($customers as $row):?>.....
```

the example code above will find duplicated customer_id and avoids printing out duplicated values as you intended. Here i used **group_by('customer-id')**